# force Jquery icon to be centered on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

I have this Jquery:

```
div.find(".CopyIntoNewTownAssociation").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-copy", text: false} });
```

and this html:

```
<a style=\"width:20px;height:20px\" class=\"CopyIntoNewTownAssociation\"></a>
```

However on the page the button is off to the right of the button. I have sever different buttons like these, and with the exact same markup, except for the icon, some are in the center, some at the bottom, some at the right. It's only off by a few pixels but this is very noticeable on a 20 px button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off i'm an idoit. The issue is that the `{}` brackets are not aligned. I wont delete the question just in-case someone else has the same question.

```
.button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-copy"}, text: false });
```

The above will center the icon. IT is the `text:false` attribute that is the key to centering the button.